# resolving "there was a pr◌blem sending a command to the program"

Tags: windows, ubuntu

At times, windows os frustrates me by showing a window which is similar to the following one:

[image: image - there was a problem sending a command to the program]

This kind of window is opened when I try to open some files/folders from my usb drive. Not all the files/folders suffer from this. But the same files/folders are accessible from my ubuntu os. Is there any way to resolve this problem so that I can use all my files/folders from windows.

Guys, please say me solution that will make my files/folders work in any windows. I wish that no one asks me to change my windows registry settings to resolve this issue. Because, it may only be making the usable in just my windows os. I want it to be used in any windows.

**P.S-1:** I am using a dual boot - windows 8 and ubuntu 14.04

**P.S-2:** I found an answer [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/fix-there-was-a-problem-sending-a-command-to-the-program-error/). The answerer had some suggestions. But he wasn't giving any single confident answer. As well, the suggestions were just the cases for a word document or an excel file. My case is different. Also, the error window opened was on clicking some web links which is again not my case.

Comment: This is typically an Office problem, not actually Windows. I suggest reinstalling Office if you can, and making sure you're on the latest patches. What version are you running? It could also be file-permission related, thanks to your your dual-boot business.

Comment: If the issue is about Office, why do I get similar message when I open some folders? I don't think that the issue is about Office.

Comment: Even I got the same message when I opened the same files and folders in my friends' computers. We are using Office 2007.

Comment: That is almost certainly a file permissions issue then. Windows reading NTFS is picky (for security reasons!) about who owns what, and if Ubuntu isn't configured to use the same security credentials it's probably wrecking the defaults your Windows installation is expecting to see.

Comment: So, what should I really need to do? And not all the files and folders are suffering from this issue.

Comment: I tried `cacls <myfile>` from cmd. It showed **Everyone:F**

Comment: Try running `SFC /scannow` from an elevated command prompt. This is the [System File Checker](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) that will check for corruption in the Windows system files.